# Springboot SOAP Web service Error (Cannot create session after response is commited)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have developed a SOAP WS using @EndPoint annotation in SpringBoot. Below is the code snippet for the endpoint class.

```
package com.xyz.cns.services.esb.custprefdetails.service.api;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.xyz.cns.services.esb.custprefdetails.service.model.GetCustomerPreferenceRequest;
import com.xyz.cns.services.esb.custprefdetails.service.model.GetCustomerPreferenceResponse;
import com.xyz.cns.services.esb.custprefdetails.service.transform.OutputTransformer;




@Endpoint
public class CustomerPreferenceDetailsWebServiceController {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://schemas.xyz.com/services/getCustomerPreferenceDetails";

/*  @Autowired
    private GetCustomerPreferenceResponse getCustomerPreferenceResponse;*/

    //@Autowired
    //CustomerPreferenceDetailsWebServiceHandler custPrefDetailsWSHandler;

    @Autowired
    OutputTransformer ot;



    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCustomerPreferenceRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCustomerPreferenceResponse getCustomerPreference(@RequestPayload GetCustomerPreferenceRequest request) {

        GetCustomerPreferenceResponse getCustomerPreferenceResponse= new GetCustomerPreferenceResponse();
        //getCustomerPreferenceResponse = custPrefDetailsWSHandler.getCustomerPreferenceDetails(request.getName());
        getCustomerPreferenceResponse = ot.transformCustPrefRes();
        return getCustomerPreferenceResponse;
    }
}
```

However, when running the service, getting a strange error:

> Appender [STDOUT_prod] failed to append. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Comment: This is incomplete code. Most likely, this is occurring because the `HttpServletResponse` is being closed. Perhaps `response#setStatus` is being called somewhere prior to this method, but it's really impossible to know based on this code snippet.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your response. Please note that I am using SpringBootStarter project and don't have any class other than this and application class. No coding involves HttpServletResponse .

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.